# t-sql doesn't display anything in the column

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

The following function doesn't return me anything in the colums even if going into debug mode it seams like the values are ok...
can someone help me out?

Obviously the select query on table [NewBiz.Labirinto].dbo.ElencoTipiEsercizio works and returns colums 2 colums:
id  |  dvr
1   |  1,2,3,4
2   |  1,3
4   |  1,2,4,5,6

```
USE [NuLab]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fun_CSVToTable]    Script Date: 29/01/2015 17:17:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Function [dbo].[fun_CSVToTable] 
(
    @Delimeter varchar(10)
)
RETURNS @RET1 TABLE (id integer, dvr VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @RET TABLE(id integer, dvr VARCHAR(50))
    DECLARE @RET2 TABLE(id integer, dvr VARCHAR(50))
    DECLARE @ID integer 
    DECLARE @LIST varchar(50)

    DECLARE @START BIGINT
    DECLARE @LASTSTART BIGINT
    DECLARE @VAR integer 

    set @ID = 0
    set @VAR = 1


    WHILE(@VAR IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        IF (@ID > (select MAX(id) from [NewBiz.Labirinto].dbo.ElencoTipiEsercizio)) BREAK
        set @LIST=(select dvr from [NewBiz.Labirinto].dbo.ElencoTipiEsercizio where [NewBiz.Labirinto].dbo.ElencoTipiEsercizio.id = @ID)
        SET @LASTSTART=0
        IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@LIST))='' RETURN

        SET @START=CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@LIST,0)

        IF @START=0
        INSERT INTO @RET(id, dvr) VALUES(@ID, SUBSTRING(@LIST,0,LEN(@LIST)+1))

        WHILE(@START >0)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @RET(id, dvr) VALUES(@ID, SUBSTRING(@LIST,@LASTSTART,@START-@LASTSTART))
            SET @LASTSTART=@START+1
            SET @START=CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@LIST,@START+1)

            IF(@START=0)
            INSERT INTO @RET(id, dvr) VALUES(@ID, SUBSTRING(@LIST,@LASTSTART,LEN(@LIST)+1))
        END

        INSERT INTO @RET2 SELECT * FROM @RET


        SET @ID = (select min(id) from [NewBiz.Labirinto].dbo.ElencoTipiEsercizio where id > @ID)

    END
    INSERT INTO @RET1 SELECT * FROM @RET2

    RETURN 
END
```

Comment: Obviously the select query is ok and returns colums like this:

Comment: What are you trying to do? Loops and cursors in SQL are a sure sign that something is wrong, and result in code that is very hard to understand and maintain. Whatever it is, it's certainly easier and a lot faster to do it using only SELECTs and joins, maybe event a CTE.

Comment: Moreover, the code seems to be coursework. Instructors will *not* be impressed if you deliver a cursor-based solution instead of one using SELECTs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos on the contrary it seems that many professors these days don't understand that looping is horrible for performance. ;)

Comment: This appears to a very specialized string splitter. You might want to take a look at this. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: This was for a learning purpose... so this is why ik'm doing it this way... In any case i'll se if i can post the solution later on. Thank you anyway